# How to check if ICMP blocking is enabled in a system..?

Tags: command-line, ping, proc, tcp-ip, terminal-server

A VLAN pool enabled newly is not pinging the device. Connectivity issues are not there.

- Can this be because if ICMP Blocking is enabled?
- How to check the status of the same?

Comment: Why you don't give feedback for your questions?! Why you just asked and go away?! You can have to reply and mark answers when it's valid...  take a look http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: This is done... pardon the delay..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check whether ICMP is enabled or disabled run the command:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

The output is 0 or 1:

- 0 means that ICMP is enabled
- 1 means that ICMP is disabled

If it's **disabled** and you want to **enable** it:

- change 1 to 0 in the above file
- Or run the command:

  ```
  iptables  -I  INPUT  -i  ech0  -p   icmp  -s  0/0  -d  0/0   -j  ACCEPT
  ```

Comment: This is clear and it works...!

Comment: @kiranbbnl Good for you, to keep having asnwers to your questions you should always give your feedback with correct or not, If the answer solves your problem you should upvote and mark as answer else when you have sufficient reputation you can downvote. But for now just keep feeding back your questions